# Regrex to allow decimal input in increments of .05

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a regrex expression for Survey123 that will allow input of a number with two decimal places in increments of .05 (I'm repurposing an ex-colleagues's code that allows input in increments of .5). I've not really used regrex before and understanding the syntax is a bit challenging.

The line which I'm working from is;

```
regex(., '^\d{0,2}(?:.[0,5])?$')
```

which was designed to allow input of a number in increments of .5, I modified it to

```
regex(., '^\d{0,2}(?:.[0-9][0,5])?$')
```

to allow increments of .05. However, this only accepts numbers which end in 5. For example, this permits 9.15 but 9.1 or 9.10 are unacceptable (and I want them to be acceptable). As the **[0,5]** works in the old expression and allows 40, 40.0 or 40.5 I thought it would work, but can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: First of all, `(?:.[0,5])?` must be `(?:\.[05])?` as unescaped dot matches any char. Next, if you want to allow `9.1`, the digit you match before last `0` or `5` must be optional. `'^\d{0,2}(?:\.\d?[05])?$'` should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your regex is not quite correct. It doesn't allow `9.1` because the final decimal must be a 0 or 5. Instead of making the most significant decimal optional you want to make the least significant decimal optional. `^\d{0,2}(?:\.\d[05]?)?$`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions, they didnt quite work for me but gave me a bit more understanding. It was the ? after the token that made the difference, and exhanging `,` for a `|` to make the second character after the decimal 0 **or** 5. The code which seems to give me what I want is;

```
regex(., '^\d{0,2}(?:.[0-9][0|5]?)?$')
```

I'm still quite in the dark when it comes to regrex, but it helped to visualise things when I came across another article explaining that the [0-9] was the first character after the decimal point, and what I had down as [0,5] was the second character after the decimal point - and I wanted that second character to end in a 0 or 5, or be optional (you could put in 9.1 instead of needing 9.10).thats where `?` was useful, and then the `|` for 0 or 5.

I was tempted to have another function to just round the input, but my colleagues like to have input on a form restricted to certain values. We are using an ArcGS survey123 form, and I'm editing the xlsx form in the background. Its easy enough to constrain the entry to values within a certain range, but the regrex was needed to have values input in those 0.05 increments. We are collecting data from a few project partners, and when things aren;t constrained all sorts of values can be input by mistake which then takes a long time to bottom-out.

Comment: `[0|5]` is wrong. `[ ... ]` is a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). It matches any of the characters in it. So your `[0|5]` matches either a `0` or a `5` or a `|` character.

Answer (score -1):

Add the character `?` after a token to make it optional. So, to make the `[0,5]` optional, you'd write `[0,5]?`. Your entire regex then becomes `^\d{0,2}(?:.[0-9][0,5]?)?$`

--

There are other mistakes in this regex. The character `.` matches any character, not just a literal full stop, so the original post will not just match `40.5` but also `40,5`, `40↨5`, and even `4005` (which might be a problem since you're only expecting two-digit numbers!). You should use `\.` to match only a literal full stop.

And the comma in `[0,5]` will match a literal comma, so `9.1,` will match. You meant to use `[05]`.

`[0-9]` and `\d` mean the same thing, you should be consistent in which one you use. This isn't a mistake, but it's a bit harder to read. I like `\d` because it's shorter.

So, putting all those together, I get... `^\d{0,2}(?:\.\d[05]?)?$`

--

All in all though - are you sure regexes are the right approach here? This is clearly going to be converted into a decimal number. Why not do that conversion first, and then check that the number you get is a multiple of 0.05? That will probably be easier to write.